# Please assist if possible for a file /folder issue

Tags: windows, microsoft

I have a problem with a folder. I transferred it from a drive in order to zip it then archive it, How ever once I zipped the folder, and transferred the zipped contents back. I went to delete the unzipped counterpart of the folder. (I have attached a photo of the folder) but it says windows cannot locate the files/folder, there are no files left in the folder though, just remnants of the folder structure, but it simply wont go away, I really don't want to reformat the drive in order to get to it, because that would mean purchasing a drive to transfer the other data over. is there any way to get rid of this, I have tried numerous powershell, and cmd commands but its just persistent. I have scanned the folder but the comodo AV says it cannot locate the file/folders. I have tried a free file deleter but that didnt work (didnt think it would but you never know) I'm at a loss.

[image: This image shows the folder and properties]

[image: This image of delete window output]

Comment: Sound like filesystem corruption. You should back up the data.

Comment: yeah the data is archived and saved, i just cant get rid of the remnants of it. its just an annoyance more than anything, it could stay there but the problem with that is it annoys me that i cant find a solution. haha, if its not supposed to be there it will eat me alive lol

Comment: I mean _all_ data on the volume. There is considerable risk `chkdsk` will destroy more when attempting to repair.

Comment: ohhhh okay ill take that on board for sure. id rather not loose all my data

Comment: Is this an SD card or flash drive?

Comment: A 4tb Harddrive